# update date values in a table created in sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a table using the below query

```
CREATE TABLE job_history (
  EMPLOYEE_ID decimal(6,0) NOT NULL,
  START_DATE date NOT NULL,
  END_DATE date  NOT NULL,
  JOB_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  DEPARTMENT_ID decimal(4,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID,START_DATE)
)
```

And when I try to update values in the created table using the below query

```
INSERT INTO job_history VALUES
(102, '1993-01-13', '1998-07-24', 'IT_PROG', 60),
(101, '1989-09-21', '1993-10-27', 'AC_ACCOUNT', 111),
(103, '1993-10-28', '1997-03-15', 'AC_MGR', 110),
(201, '1996-02-17', '1999-12-19', 'MK_REP', 20),
(114, '1998-03-24', '1999-12-31', 'ST_CLERK', 51),
(122, '1999-01-01', '1999-12-31', 'ST_CLERK', 50),
(200, '1987-09-17', '1993-06-17', 'AD_ASST', 90),
(176, '1998-03-24', '1998-12-31', 'SA_REP', 80),
(175, '1999-01-01', '1999-12-31', 'SA_MAN', 81),
(201, '1994-07-01', '1998-12-31', 'AC_ACCOUNT', 91),
(0, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '', 0)
```

I get an error saying `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`  how to resolve this? I tried it for .

Comment: Probably because of your last value '0000-00-00' ? Can you try removing it and see if it works?

Comment: please format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your '0000-00-00' expresion like @Minh mention.

Instead make the field nuleable, and use null values for undetermination.

Comment: Many Thanks Minh, Turing85, Giorgi Nakeuri, dizballanze for the answers  and  corrections nd suggestions. Together they resolve my quest. it is working fine now after editing the date time range.

Answer (score 0):

The range of date type is `0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31`, so there is no '0000-00-00'. Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.100).aspx